# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN with different table values

Tags: postgresql

Let's suppose I have two tables EBAY and AMAZON. In EBAY table I have to add a new column:
price that must be greater then AMAZON.price, it should be be set for 10 by default, greater then 0 and not more the 4 digits.

My current query:

```
ALTER TABLE ebay ADD COUMN priece numeric(4,2) DEFAULT 10 check (priece >0);//BUT I need to compare EBAY.price > AMAZON.PRIECE.
```

Comment: first: you would need trigger for that. second: `compare EBAY.price > AMAZON.PRIECE` needs `where ebay.id = amazon.id` otherwise it loses sence

Answer (score 0):

1. *check on other table row:*

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to
>   variables other than columns of the current row.

So if you want to compare `EBAY.price` against `AMAZON.PRIECE` you need trigger.

2. *default*

`DEFAULT 10` will set value of priece to `10` if the value is not specified

3. *4 digits*
   `numeric(4,2)` limits value to two digits before decimals and two after, if you want four digits befour decimals, use `numeric(6,2)` or `numeric(4,0)` or whatever you want for decimals